# Why was the existential quantifier symbol ∃ based off of an inverted "E"?

Tags: logic, notation, math-history, quantifiers

Peano introduced a number of logical symbols still used today:

- ∨ (from Latin ***v***el)
- ∧ (inverted ∨)
- ∃

This inversion of Latin letters as symbols (and inversion of symbols to signify their 'opposite' operation) was followed by later logicians:

- ∀ (Gentzen, [1935](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0039?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B184%5D%7D): inverted A from *"**A**ll-Zeichen"*, by analogy to ∃)
- ⊥ (inverted ⊤)

I had always assumed that ∃ stood for "E" in ***"E***xistential" / "there **E**xists", but Peano wrote and introduced this symbol in French, not using any words beginning 'E':

> Mais nous préférons l'indiquer par la nouvelle notation
>
> Ǝ*a*
>
> qu'on peut lire « il y a des *a* ».
>
> - [*Formulaire de mathématiques*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k84142s/f48.item), Peano (1897)

**So why did he choose an inverted "E"?**

---

<sup>[*Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html)</sup>
<sup>[What came first, the $\forall$ or the $\exists$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183278/what-came-first-the-forall-or-the-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What came first, the $\forall$ or the $\exists$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183278/what-came-first-the-forall-or-the-exists)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for this, unfortunately it doesn't explain the origin of the symbol, just it's earliest occurrence.

Comment: @JMoravitz the answer there does not say anything about why Russell used it (doesn't say if it comes from inverted "Exists") so this does not seem like a duplicate.

Comment: BTW, this might be a good question for [History of Science and Math StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: See [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html): "Peano used the $\exists$ in volume II, number 1, of his *Formulaire de mathematiqués*, which was published in 1897, according to Cajori vol. 2, page 300."

Comment: I seem to recall that quantifier $E$ was used for a while before $\exists$ was introduced.  If so, that would be a strong hint of where $\exists$ came from.

Comment: Correct: Peano used also French : [Existence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_(philosophie)).

Comment: @GEdgar if you can find a reference to that that'd be great.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a duplicate - the proposed question does not answer why an inverted 'E' was chosen as the symbol.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yep I'm aware, and I suspected this was the source of the symbol, but he doesn't use any such term in his introduction and explanation of "∃".

Comment: Why so ? In page 47 of *Formulaire* that you have linked above it is written : "signifie "il y a des $a$", "les $a$ **existent**" ".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ah, true - thanks! (though he uses that phrase when he's describing the earlier equivalent notation, and not ∃ itself, which is why I suppose I didn't register it) - that would serve as an answer (if the question were to be reopened).